# Cómo hacer corresponder un elemento de una lista a otro de otra lista

Tags: python

Si tenemos `a=['nombre 12','nombre 22']` y `b=['1','2']`, ¿cómo puedo asociar el valor de la posición `0` de la lista **a** a la posición `0` de la lista **b** y que nos imprima algo así?:

```
nombre 11 1
nombre 22 2
```

Comment: Bienvenido y.hobbi a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] para que conozcas mas sobre el sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). También revisa [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Has intentado algo?

Answer (score 3):

Para eso sirve [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#zip):

```
a=['nombre 12','nombre 22']
b=['1','2']
for nombre, dato in zip(a,b):
   print(nombre, dato)
```

Si las dos listas no son de la misma longitud, el bucle terminará cuando termine la más corta. Si quieres que no sea así, puedes usar `itertools.zip_longest()` que seguirá una vez que termine la lista más corta, rellenando con un valor por defecto (que puedes especificar) hasta alcanzar a la más larga. Por ejemplo:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

a=['nombre 12','nombre 22', "nombre 34"]
b=['1','2']
for nombre, dato in zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=-1):
   print(nombre, dato)
```

---

```
nombre 12 1
nombre 22 2
nombre 34 -1
```